# Uploading file with 45MB size using data loader keep failing

Tags: data-loader

I'm trying to upload files to Salesforce using data loader and the file size is around 45MB every time I'm trying to upload the file I got error with maximum retries reached, any idea how to deploy large file using data loader.

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Dataloader can handle up to 5 million records and upload file size is 50 MB and I suspect it shouldn't be a problem with dataloader.  Can you try using batch size limit to 1 (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000322505&type=1&mode=1).  Also if possible kindly add screenshot of the error message.

Comment: @Vinay I added screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Data Loader uses the SOAP API, which has an inherent limit of 50MB. SOAP is an XML-based protocol, so binary data has to be Base64 encoded, which turns three bytes into four, effectively reducing the maximum payload for binary data by 25%. The actual maximum ends up being around 37.5MB (less than 39,321,600, as the bytes in the protocol itself reduce this number further). This is called out in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentversion.htm) in various places:

> The maximum file size you can upload via the SOAP API is 50 MB. When a document is uploaded or downloaded via the API, it is converted to base64 and stored in VersionData. This conversion increases the document size by approximately 37%. Account for the base64 conversion increase so that the file you plan to upload is less than 50 MB after conversion.

If you want to upload files larger than that, you need something that can support large binary data (as described in [Insert or Update Blob Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm)). You would either need to modify the [source code](https://github.com/forcedotcom/dataloader) or find another ETL tool that supports large files. You'll want to do your own research on this subject. I'm not aware of any specific tools out there that can support this.